# Tween animation flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to play an animation when a button is clicked. On the first press, the widget rotates 180 degrees, on the second press, another 180 degrees (that is, it returns to its original position). How can I do this?

Simulated gesture detector button

```
                      Expanded(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => setState(() {
                            if (tapValue == 0) {
                              tapValue++;
                              animController.forward();
                              beginValue = 0.0;
                              endValue = 0.5;
                            } else {
                              tapValue--;
                              animController.forward();
                            }
                          }),
                          child: Container(
                            child: Image.asset('assets/images/enableAsset.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

The widget I want to rotate

```
            child: CustomPaint (
              painter: SmileyPainter(),
              child: RotationTransition(
                turns: Tween(begin: beginValue, end: endValue,).animate(animController),
                child: CustomPaint (
                  painter: Smile(),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

animation controller

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    animController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is only to rotate a widget, I would recommend avoiding a controller. Not only will this simplify your code but it will also save you the chore of disposing it.

I have come to realize that pretty much any controller can be avoided using the `TweenAnimationBuilder` widget.

Here is an example of how to to make it work for your case:

```
Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _rotationAngle += pi;
          print(_rotationAngle);
          setState(() {

          });
        },
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TweenAnimationBuilder(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: _rotationAngle),
          builder: (BuildContext context, double value, Widget child) {
            return Transform.rotate(
              angle: value,
              child: child,
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 500,
            width: 50,
            color: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
else {tapValue--;
      animController.forward();
}
```

to

```
else {tapValue--;
      animController.reverce();
}
```